# best practice for tracking new/seen items

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

So I'm making productivity app for myself and ppl around me. There will be a lots of different stuff related to different type groups or individual persons for different types of reasons.

Is there some best practice approach, algorythm or guidelines to do this properly that I should know before I screw everything up?

If it matters, I'm using GAE, Python, NDB.

CLARIFICATION EDIT:

- someone contributed to household's savings account
- Someone posted a picture to album of the party that I attended
- somone from household added someting to shopping list
- i received a direct message
- someone uploaded a documentg to project workspace etc

I need to keep track of which items are new and which have been seen.

Comment: I suggest clarifying the question... otherwise, it is likely to be closed for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a few ways to go about this, and using Google Cloud SQL would probably make your life easier for this. What you could do though is add a BooleanProperty to your entity types for example, named 'New', that would be set to 'True' by default. You would need to create an algorithm that would check through the datastore to return you any entity who's 'New' BooleanProperty is set to True, and then set it to False once it's returned.

Comment: what if it's more like a post on the forums - where there are more than one intended recepient? Should I make determine intended audience and list them all in the item, or make tracking entity for everyone or maybe make class "Seen", that has item's un user's key, once user sees the item entity is created, if I can't find the entity that contains item's and user's keys, then I conclude user hasn't seen it... first and last options seem the most practical.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your question. So yes having to check on multiple users that can all have different status makes this a little more complicated but the best way would probably be to make a class 'Seen, as you said. A determined audience list could work too though but it seems less efficient. So when the user logins, it checks the item keys and checks if there's a Seen entity with their user key, if not then that entity is displayed as new, then the Seen entity is created. Your idea seems the best way to go about it to me.